# Unable to use a local file using spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to execute a spark word count program. My input file and output dir are on local and not on HDFS. When I execute the code, I get input directory not found exception.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object WordCount {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark   = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).master("yarn").getOrCreate()
    val input   = args(0)
    val output  = args(1)
    val text    = spark.sparkContext.textFile("input",1)
    val outPath = text.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    val words   = outPath.map(w => (w,1))
    val wc      = words.reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x+y))

    wc.saveAsTextFile("output")
  }
}
```

Spark Submit:

```
spark-submit --class com.practice.WordCount sparkwordcount_2.11-0.1.jar --files home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/sample /home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/wordout
```

I am using the option `--files` to fetch the local input file and point the output to output dir in spark-submit. When I submit the jar using spark-submit, it says input path does not exist:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://dev/user/hmusr/input
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things:

```
val text = spark.sparkContext.textFile(input,1)
```

To use a variable, remove double quotes, is `input` not `"input"`.

You expect input and output as an argument so in spark submit after jar (without --files) and use master as `local`.

Also, use `file://` to use local files.

Your `spark-submit` should look something like:

```
spark-submit --master local[2] \
--class com.practice.WordCount \
sparkwordcount_2.11-0.1.jar \
file:///home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/sample \
file:///home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/wordout
```

Comment: Changed the line to:     val text    = spark.sparkContext.textFile(input,1) and spark submit to: SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --master local[2] --class com.practice.WordCount sparkwordcount_2.11-0.1.jar file:///home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/sample file:///home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/wordout

Now I am getting the exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
File file:/home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/sample does not exist when the file is clearly available in the dir:
[hmusr@ip-10-211-871-8 inputdir]$ ls =>
sample  sparkwordcount_2.11-0.1.jar

Comment: How do you launch? .master("yarn") what is? I thought you want to execute in local because of that I told you --master local[2]

Comment: I am launching it from local (linux cli). The input file: sample exists in /home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/. I used your suggestion to add master  local[2] in spark-submit

Comment: I suppose you removed  .master("yarn") line in code, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I removed it from the code and it is working now. Thanks from a Liverpool fan :-)

Comment: I could only read hdfs file in pyspark but not the local ones. I spent hours trying to figure out why until I found this solution. In my case I have to use ``file:///`` in order to read the file.